# Why can't I find a CERT.RSA file in my Android APK?

Tags: macos, certificates

I need to view the certificate of an Android APK, however when I look in the META-INF folder, there is no CERT.RSA file. I know that somehow the APK must be signed, because I was able to put it on an android emulator and run it, and Android won't install any unsigned apps, so it must be signed.
I just really need to actually see the signature but I cannot find it.

I am using Android Studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154): your question isn't where the cert is, but how you can verify the signature, right? The tool for that is `apksigner` (can be found in Android's build tools), and you run it like `apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs *.apk`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the "CERT.RSA" file is called something else. No idea why. I have often found the certificate file to be called something".RSA".

For example, when I decompile the "wp.wattpad" APK, it has its certificate saved as "BNDLTOOL.RSA"

My advice to you would be to find the file in the META-INF folder that has the extension ".RSA". It is probably the certificate.

Comment: Does every android app has META-INF folder ? I dont find it anywhere

Comment: In my case it was saved as KEY0.RSA

Answer (score 0):

1. check your mini sdk version, if it is >23, the v1 scheme signature will be ignored.
2. Is it only signed in v2?

Only the v1 scheme signature needs *.RSA files. You can use the apk signature tools which under the android sdk dir to verify the apk is signed.